# convert timeslots from API to selected timezone

Tags: javascript, php, api, yii, timezone

I'm having this problem where I need to convert the timeslots that I got from the API according to the user selection.

Here is my code for the timeslots dropdown:

```
<!-- timeslot -->
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane text-left" id="timeslot">
  <div class="margin-bottom-2x form-font"><b>Select your timezone: </b>
    <select class="js-Selector timezone-selector">
        <option value="Etc/GMT+12">(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
        <option value="US/Alaska">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
        <option value="America/Los_Angeles">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <option value="America/Tijuana">(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California</option>
        <option value="US/Arizona">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>
        <option value="America/Chihuahua">(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan</option>
        <option value="US/Mountain">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <option value="America/Managua">(GMT-06:00) Central America</option>
        <option value="US/Central">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <option value="America/Mexico_City">(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey</option>
        <option value="Canada/Saskatchewan">(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="America/Bogota">(GMT-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco</option>
        <option value="US/Eastern">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
        <option value="US/East-Indiana">(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>
        <option value="Canada/Atlantic">(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)</option>
        <option value="America/Caracas">(GMT-04:00) Caracas, La Paz</option>
        <option value="America/Manaus">(GMT-04:00) Manaus</option>
        <option value="America/Santiago">(GMT-04:00) Santiago</option>
        <option value="Canada/Newfoundland">(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland</option>
        <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">(GMT-03:00) Brasilia</option>
        <option value="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires, Georgetown</option>
        <option value="America/Godthab">(GMT-03:00) Greenland</option>
        <option value="America/Montevideo">(GMT-03:00) Montevideo</option>
        <option value="America/Noronha">(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic</option>
        <option value="Atlantic/Cape_Verde">(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is.</option>
        <option value="Atlantic/Azores">(GMT-01:00) Azores</option>
        <option value="Africa/Casablanca">(GMT+00:00) Casablanca, Monrovia, Reykjavik</option>
        <option value="Etc/Greenwich">(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option>
        <option value="Europe/Amsterdam">(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</option>
        <option value="Europe/Belgrade">(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
        <option value="Europe/Brussels">(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
        <option value="Europe/Sarajevo">(GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb</option>
        <option value="Africa/Lagos">(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa</option>
        <option value="Asia/Amman">(GMT+02:00) Amman</option>
        <option value="Europe/Athens">(GMT+02:00) Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul</option>
        <option value="Asia/Beirut">(GMT+02:00) Beirut</option>
        <option value="Africa/Cairo">(GMT+02:00) Cairo</option>
        <option value="Africa/Harare">(GMT+02:00) Harare, Pretoria</option>
        <option value="Europe/Helsinki">(GMT+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius</option>
        <option value="Asia/Jerusalem">(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem</option>
        <option value="Europe/Minsk">(GMT+02:00) Minsk</option>
        <option value="Africa/Windhoek">(GMT+02:00) Windhoek</option>
        <option value="Asia/Kuwait">(GMT+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh, Baghdad</option>
        <option value="Europe/Moscow">(GMT+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd</option>
        <option value="Africa/Nairobi">(GMT+03:00) Nairobi</option>
        <option value="Asia/Tbilisi">(GMT+03:00) Tbilisi</option>
        <option value="Asia/Tehran">(GMT+03:30) Tehran</option>
        <option value="Asia/Muscat">(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat</option>
        <option value="Asia/Baku">(GMT+04:00) Baku</option>
        <option value="Asia/Yerevan">(GMT+04:00) Yerevan</option>
        <option value="Asia/Kabul">(GMT+04:30) Kabul</option>
        <option value="Asia/Yekaterinburg">(GMT+05:00) Yekaterinburg</option>
        <option value="Asia/Karachi">(GMT+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent</option>
        <option value="Asia/Calcutta">(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</option>
        <option value="Asia/Calcutta">(GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenapura</option>
        <option value="Asia/Katmandu">(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu</option>
        <option value="Asia/Almaty">(GMT+06:00) Almaty, Novosibirsk</option>
        <option value="Asia/Dhaka">(GMT+06:00) Astana, Dhaka</option>
        <option value="Asia/Rangoon">(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)</option>
        <option value="Asia/Bangkok">(GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
        <option value="Asia/Krasnoyarsk">(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk</option>
        <option value="Asia/Hong_Kong">(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur">(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore</option>
        <option value="Asia/Irkutsk">(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar</option>
        <option value="Australia/Perth">(GMT+08:00) Perth</option>
        <option value="Asia/Taipei">(GMT+08:00) Taipei</option>
        <option value="Asia/Tokyo">(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo</option>
        <option value="Asia/Seoul">(GMT+09:00) Seoul</option>
        <option value="Asia/Yakutsk">(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk</option>
        <option value="Australia/Adelaide">(GMT+09:30) Adelaide</option>
        <option value="Australia/Darwin">(GMT+09:30) Darwin</option>
        <option value="Australia/Brisbane">(GMT+10:00) Brisbane</option>
        <option value="Australia/Canberra">(GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney</option>
        <option value="Australia/Hobart">(GMT+10:00) Hobart</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Guam">(GMT+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby</option>
        <option value="Asia/Vladivostok">(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok</option>
        <option value="Asia/Magadan">(GMT+11:00) Magadan, Solomon Is., New Caledonia</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Auckland">(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Fiji">(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.</option>
        <option value="Pacific/Tongatapu">(GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa</option>
     </select>
```

And this is the code to get the timeslots from the API:

```
 <b>Select a timeslot: </b>
    </br>Schedule is based on mentors availability & subject to approval.
         <span id="spinner-mentor-checkDate"><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Checking...</small></span>
          </div>
              <div class="hidden">
                   <div class="col-xs-12 text-left clearfix">
                       <span id="box-BookSlotForm_date">
                          <?php echo $form->bsTextField($model, 'date'); ?>
                       </span>

                       <span id="box-BookSlotForm_time">
                           <?php echo $form->bsTextField($model, 'time'); ?>
                       </span>

                       <span class="input-group" style="max-width:8em;">
                          <span class="input-group-addon noborder">GMT</span>
                             <?php echo $form->bsTextField($model, 'timezone', array('readonly'=>'readonly')) ?>
                        </span>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="full-width text-left margin-top-md">
              <div id="box-nearbyDates"></div>
           </div>
```

And this is the javascript to get the timeslots from the API:

```
// nearby
    $('#box-nearbyDates').html('');
    var programId = $('#BookSlotForm_programId').val();
    var mentorId = $('#BookSlotForm_mentorId').val();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        url: baseUrl+'/mentor/api/getAvailableTimeSlotsRecently',
        data: { programId:programId, mentorId:mentorId},
    }).done(function(json) {
        if(json.status == 'success')
        {
            var htmlNearby = '';
            timeSpan = 30*60*1000;
            $.each(json.data.slots, function(index, timeslots) {

                if(timeslots.length>0) htmlNearby += '<fieldset class="margin-bottom-lg"><legend class="nopadding nearby-date-font">'+moment(index).format('ddd, YYYY-MMM-DD')+'</legend>';

                $.each(timeslots, function(indexTimeslot, timeslot){
                    var hour = timeslot.split(':')[0];
                    var min = timeslot.split(':')[1];

                    var newDate = new Date();
                    newDate.setHours(hour);
                    newDate.setMinutes(min);

                    var afterAddition = new Date(newDate.getTime() + $program->length*60000); //Adding 30 mins to the slot
                    var newHour = afterAddition.getHours() < 10 ? '0'+ afterAddition.getHours():afterAddition.getHours();

                    var newMin = afterAddition.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0'+ afterAddition.getMinutes(): afterAddition.getMinutes();

                    htmlNearby += '<a class="btn-timeslot-mentor btn-sm btn-white margin-sm btn-timeslotSuggestion timeslot-font" data-date="'+index+'" data-time="'+timeslot+'">'+timeslot + ' - ' + newHour + ':' + newMin + '</a>';

                });
                htmlNearby += '</fieldset>';
            });
            $('#box-nearbyDates').html(htmlNearby);
        }

    }).always(function(){
    });
```

So now how can I change the time from the API to based on the timezone selected from the dropdown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ctoc_timezone

The js can handle div tags and convert them to particular timezone. Read the documentation.

The typical format it accepts is -

`<div data-ctoc-timezone data-ctoc-time="Mar 01 2013 05:30:00 +5:30" data-ctoc-req-zone="" data-ctoc-req-format=""></div>`

Output:

`Fri Mar 01 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

U can set the 'data-ctoc-req-zone' to your required zone and convert time like-

`<div data-ctoc-timezone data-ctoc-time="Mar 01 2013 05:30:00 +5:30" data-ctoc-req-zone="America/Lima" data-ctoc-req-format=""> </div>`

Output:
`Thu Feb 28 2013 19:00:00`